# Cloning an object with Knockout that has an observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model called `ProductsViewModel`
This contains an observableArray of `ProductViewModel`

A `ProductViewModel` also contains an observableArray - of `ProductPriceViewModel`

One feature I have is that I can duplicate a `ProductViewModel` and insert it into the `ProductsViewModel` array.

When I clone using:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(itemToCopy));
```

It doesn't appear to copy correctly - the `prices` observable array, isn't populated with `ProductPriceViewModel`s - just Object

Here's the view models

```
var ProductsViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.products = ko.observableArray([new ProductViewModel()]);

    self.addNewProduct = function() {
        self.products.push(new ProductViewModel());
    };

    self.duplicateProduct = function() {
        var itemToCopy = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.products(), function(item) {
            return item.visible();
        });

        //if i look at itemToCopy.prices() it is an array of ProductViewModel

        var newItem = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(itemToCopy));
        //if i look at newItem.prices() it is an array of Object

        self.products.push(newItem);
    };
};

var ProductViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.visible = ko.observable(true);

    self.prices = ko.observableArray([new ProductPriceViewModel()]);

    self.addPrice = function() {
        self.prices.push(new ProductPriceViewModel());
    };
};

var ProductPriceViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.price = ko.observable();
};
```

Comment: What do you want to duplicate? Product? But why in this case you expected itemToCopy.products() it should be itemToCopy.prices().

Comment: Sorry, have updated the comment. Should have been .prices()

Comment: Want to duplicate Product - which *contains* an observableArray of ProductPrices....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by passing in a mapping configuration like this:

```
var mapping = {
    'prices': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new ServicePriceViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};
```

on

```
var newItem = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(productToCopy), mapping);
```

and changing my `ProductPriceViewModel` to accept data as a parameter:

```
var ProductPriceViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.description = ko.observable();
    self.price = ko.observable();
    self.priceIsFrom = ko.observable();

    if (data)
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};
```